# Why animation does not work?

Tags: animation, react-native

Why animation does not work?

All code

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    View,
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    WebView,
    Linking,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Animated,
    Keyboard, 
    TextInput,
    KeyboardAvoidingView
} from 'react-native';

import {
    Button,
    Text,
    Container,
    Card,
    CardItem,
    Body,
    Content,
    Header,
    Title,
    Left,
    Icon,
    Right,
    Form,
    Picker,
    Item
} from 'native-base';

import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { styles, colors, paddings, fonts } from '../styles';
import DefaultInput from "./DefaultInput";
import validate from "./Validation";
import ModalComponent from "./Modal";
import ModalDropdown from 'react-native-modal-dropdown';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo';
import CheckBox from 'react-native-check-box';

class CheckIn extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);  
    this.inputMarginTop = new Animated.Value(8);

}

componentWillMount () {
    this.keyboardWillShowSub = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillShow', this.keyboardWillShow);
    this.keyboardWillHideSub = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillHide', this.keyboardWillHide);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardWillShowSub.remove();
    this.keyboardWillHideSub.remove();
  }


 keyboardWillShow = (event) => {
    Animated.timing(this.inputMarginTop, {
      duration: event.duration,
      toValue: 2,
    }).start();
  };

  keyboardWillHide = (event) => {
    Animated.timing(this.inputMarginTop, {
      duration: event.duration,
      toValue: 8,
    }).start();
  };


    render() {
       console.log(this.inputMarginTop._value);
        return (
                  <View style={{height: '100%', alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                          <TextInput
                            style={{width: '90%', height: 20, borderWidth:1, marginTop: 100}}
                          />
                          <View style={{width: '90%'}}>
                              <Animated.Text style={{marginLeft: 10, marginBottom: 8, marginTop: `${this.inputMarginTop}%`}}>Имя</Animated.Text>
                           </View>
                    </View>
        );
    }
}
export default CheckIn;
```

Important parts of the code

```js
this.inputMarginTop = new Animated.Value(8);
```

```js
<View style={{width: '90%'}}>
   <Animated.Text style={{marginLeft: 10, marginBottom: 8, marginTop: `${this.inputMarginTop}%`}}>Имя</Animated.Text>
</View>
```

Why animation does not work? Why animation does not work? Why animation does not work? Why animation does not work? Why animation does not work? Why animation does not work? Why animation does not work? Why animation does not work? Why animation does not work? Why animation does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist of all, which device are you running on? if it is Android, then it will not work, find it here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard.html

> keyboardWillShow as well as keyboardWillHide are generally not
>   available on Android since there is no native corresponding event.

If it is iOS, then you should use `Animated.View` instead of `Animated.Text`.
Try the following code:

```
<Animated.View style={{width: '90%', marginLeft: 10, marginBottom: 8, marginTop: `${this.inputMarginTop}%`}}>
   <Text>Имя</Text>
</Animated.View>
```

Generally, for `Text` component, you should move all the position/layout related style to its parent `View`, the style in `Text` is normally related to `font` itself, like `color`, `fontSize`, `fontStyle` etc.

Also try `console.log(event.duration)` to make sure the event contains duration which is not 0.

Comment: I launch the code on Expo.I want to make cross-platform